# Set a variable within a Unity class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently following a brackeys tutorial on dialogue, however I want to import multiple names, as well as multiple lines of dialogue along with them, through a text file rather than handwriting them. This differs greatly from the tutorial, so I'm stuck on creating a Dialogue class. Here's what I wrote up:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

 [System.Serializable]
public class Dialogue {
    // text file input
    public TextAsset textFile;
    // list containing each line of the text file
    protected string[] textLines;
    // lists containing names and dialogues (written in the file like so: Bob;I like pancakes)
    protected string[] names;
    protected string[] dialogues;

    // splits up the text file into the list of lines
    textLines = textFile.text.Split('\n');
    // iterates over the course of the list of lines, splitting up the names and dialogue, then sorting each into its respective list
    for (int i = 0; i <= textLines.Length - 1; i++) {
        names.Add(textLines[i].Split(';')[0]);
        dialogue.Add(textLines[i].Split(';')[1]);
    }
}
```

Unity, however, does not like this, and spits out loads of errors such as:

> Assets\scripts\Dialogue.cs(12,15): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

and

> Assets\scripts\Dialogue.cs(12,36): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

among others.

I assume there are limits when working with unity classes such as this one, however I evidently don't know them, and after looking through the internet, I was unable to find them. Any help with this is appreciated!

Comment: Around this `textLines = textFile.text.Split('\n');` and the following `for` loop there should probably either be a **method** or **constructor** ... They can't just be in class level

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: I have never used Unity before, so take this with a grain of salt.*

---

You can only assign class fields when you declare them, and you can only place `for` loops inside functions and properties (`get` and `set` are technically functions). Though class fields ARE modified in the application's lifetime, so there is no need to worry.

Also, `string[]`s do **not** have the `.Add()` method in them. Either convert the array into a `List<string>`, do an expensive operation that pushes new elements into an array **or** define a fixed size for the array.

You can do this:

```
/**
 * You can do one of these:
 * protected List<string> names; (we will use this)
 * protected string[] names = new string[SOME_SIZE];
 * protected string[] names; (and push elements)
 */

void AssignTextLines() {
    // splits up the text file into the list of lines
    textLines = textFile.text.Split('\n');

    // iterates over the course of the list of lines, splitting up the names and dialogue, then sorting each into its respective list
    for (int i = 0; i < textLines.Length; /* you don't need -1! */ i++) {
        names.Add(textLines[i].Split(';')[0]); // only for List<T>!!
        dialogues.Add(textLines[i].Split(';')[1]);
    }
}
```

or this:

```
protected string[] textLines = textFile.text.Split('\n');

void Something() {
    // then do the thing above
    for (int i = 0; i < textLines.Length; i++) {
        names.Add(textLines[i].Split(';')[0]); // only for List<T>!!
        dialogues.Add(textLines[i].Split(';')[1]);
    }
}
```

---

You can also replace the `for` loop with a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (string txt in textLines) {
    names.Add(txt.Split(';')[0]); // only for List<T>!!
    dialogues.Add(txt.Split(';')[1]);
}
```

Comment: Also, `dialogues` is misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is that you have written these:

```
// splits up the text file into the list of lines
textLines = textFile.text.Split('\n');
// iterates over the course of the list of lines, splitting up the names and dialogue, then sorting each into its respective list
for (int i = 0; i <= textLines.Length - 1; i++) {
    names.Add(textLines[i].Split(';')[0]);
    dialogue.Add(textLines[i].Split(';')[1]);
}
```

Inside the class instead of a method inside the class.

---

Coming to the actual problem, I think you should use a ScriptableObject in this case. They provide an Awake (Similar to Awake in MonoBehavior) method in which you can write the above code so that it gets executed when the game starts.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName="Dialogue Asset", menuName="My Game/Dialogue Asset")]
public class Dialogue: ScriptableObject {
    // text file input
    public TextAsset textFile;
    // list containing each line of the text file
    protected string[] textLines;
    // lists containing names and dialogues (written in the file like so: Bob;I like pancakes)
    protected string[] names;
    protected string[] dialogues;

    void Awake() {
        textLines = textFile.text.Split('\n');
        for (int i = 0; i <= textLines.Length - 1; i++) {
            names.Add(textLines[i].Split(';')[0]);
            dialogue.Add(textLines[i].Split(';')[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can access the textLines and other things when the game is running. To create a new dialogue asset, you can go to Asset/My Game/Dialogue Asset from the menu bar in Unity and Edit them in the inspector. This is just a brief overview of ScriptableObject class. I suggest you watch [Scriptable Objects - Brackey's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPXvoWVabPY) to get the concept of scriptable objects better.